# file upload error in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, multer

To upload a file in node.js express I am using multer module. The code itself in a separate file is working like charm. but if I place the same code in my project(html code in one file and routing in another file) its not working.

Html code:

```
<form method="post" action="uploadgallerypic" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="gallerypic" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

corresponding routes.js code

```
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads'}));

app.post('/uploadgallerypic', function(req, res) {
        console.log("New photo added");
        console.log(req.files);
        fs.readFile(req.files.gallerypic.path, function(err, data) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("Error in reading pic from disk");
            }
            else {
                fs.writeFile('newpic.jpg', data, 'binary', function(err) {
                    console.log("Error in writing pic to disk");
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

After clicking on submit the very first statement  `console.log('New photo added')` which prints to console is not executing. Browser simply rotates and finally says 'No Data received'.  But If I create a single file with these two blocks then its working fine.

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var app = express();

var form = "<form method=\"post\" action=\"uploadgallerypic\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" >" +
    "<input type=\"file\" name=\"gallerypic\" />" +
    "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"upload\" />" +
    "</form>";

app.use(multer({dest:'./uploads/'}));

app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end(form);

});

var fs = require('fs');

app.post('/uploadgallerypic', function(req, res) {
        console.log("New photo added");
        console.log(req.files);
        fs.readFile(req.files.gallerypic.path, function(err, data) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("Error in reading pic from disk");
            }
            else {
                fs.writeFile('newpic.jpg', data, 'binary', function(err) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log("Error in writing pic to disk");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        res.redirect('/profile');
    });

app.listen(8080);
```

please tell me what I am missing here.

Edit#1
I removed `app.post('/uploadgallerypic', function(req, res)` block from routes.ejs to see the error "Cannot POST /uploadgallerypic" but I am not getting such error, browser simply rotating and says no data received. If I remove the `enctype='multipart/form-data'` satement from html code then I am getting the exact error "Cannot POST /uploadgallerypic". Is there any problem in using `enctype='multipart/form-data'`.

Please help me.

Comment: Did you try using the same (absolute) `dest` path from your single-file solution (`'/home/gopi/git/manakutumbamu/manakutumbamu/public/images/'`) in your multi-file setup (instead of `'./uploads'`)?

Comment: Yeah I did. but it didn't

Comment: How are you serving the html in the first (problematic) scenario? Does changing the `action` to `/uploadgallerypic` instead of `uploadgallerypic` work?

Comment: I tried with both. uploadgallerypic and /uploadgallerypic neither helps...:(

Comment: @Gopi follow the answer in this link it will definitely helps you.https://stackoverflow.com/a/45755235/7635845

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be minor typos...there are at least three things in the 'broken' example that are wrong/different from your 'working' example.

1) Is the `dest` value good?

In your broken example, change this line:

```
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads'}));
```

...to this:

```
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}));
```

(Note the addition of the trailing slash on the `dest` path.  Maybe not important, but I didn't go read the `multer` source to see if it matters.  I just know it matters in some other situations, such as with some situations with grunt.)

2) Your `app.post` looks off:

Change this:

```
app.post('/uploadgallerypic', function(err, res) {
```

...to this?

```
app.post('/uploadgallerypic', function(req, res) {
```

(was there a reason you had `err` in there?)

3) And related to #2...

From this:

```
fs.readFile(req.files.gallerypic.path, function(req, data) {
```

...to this:

```
fs.readFile(req.files.gallerypic.path, function(err, data) {
```

(So...did you copy the code around or rewrite it by hand and accidentally swap which argument goes where?)

Comment: Instead of adding function(err,data) in fs.readFile() I added to app.post(). Sorry...

Comment: with #1 suggestion also no use...:(

Answer (score 0):

don't directly inject `multer` into express.
like this way

```
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}));
```

instead 
1) create object of `multer`

```
var Upload = multer({
    storage: storage 
}).any('gallerypic');
```

2) create storage for gallerypic (upload file )

```
// storage for upload file.
 var storage  = multer.diskStorage({
     destination: function (req, file, callback) {
     callback(null, './file');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
     callback(null, file.originalname);
  }
 });
```

3) define your route

```
 router.post('/uploadgallerypic', postData);
```

4) Invoke multer in your route.

```
function postData(req,res){
 Upload(req, res, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error);
    }
    console.log("New photo added");
        console.log(req.files);
        fs.readFile(req.files.gallerypic.path, function(err, data) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("Error in reading pic from disk");
            }
            else {
                fs.writeFile('newpic.jpg', data, 'binary', function(err) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log("Error in writing pic to disk");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        res.redirect('/profile');
 })
}
```

refer this like : [How to return id of uploaded file (upload with multer in nodejs express app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889947/how-to-return-id-of-uploaded-file-upload-with-multer-in-nodejs-express-app/45890307#45890307)